# StringTemplate performance issue

Tags: string-manipulation

`StringTemplate` introduced in version 10 is very convenient in constructing formatted data. However, it seems to have a huge performance issue.

Consider this example:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {20000, 3}];

data1 = 
   StringRiffle[
    Apply[StringTemplate["<`1`,`2`,`3`>,`1`,`2`,`3`"], data, {1}], 
    ",\n"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.54397, Null} *)

data2 = 
   StringRiffle[
    Apply["<" <> ToString[#1] <> "," <> ToString[#2] <> "," <> 
       ToString[#3] <> ">" <> "," <> ToString[#1] <> "," <> 
       ToString[#2] <> "," <> ToString[#3] &, data, {1}], 
    ",\n"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.186368, Null} *)

data1 == data2
(* True *)
```

We see that although the `StringTemplate` version is short and clean, it is **35X slower** than the ordinary `StringJoin` version.

Do you consider this a bug?

Comment: I would consider it worth reporting.

Comment: FYI: reported with [CASE:3699358].

Comment: Have you received any reply from the support?

Comment: No body use `StringTemplate`? Why no one cares about the performance? The performance issue still remains to date with 12.2 !